# My files in my folder of ./app in angular project have been removed

Tags: angular5

in the last month I've working in a project using Angular 5. 
The problem is that now, I have lost everything except "app.component.css" in my folder /app. I don't know what happened. Here is some information about angular version:

- Angular CLI: 1.5.4
- Node: 9.2.0 OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 5.1.1 ...
  animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms ... http,
  language-service, platform-browser ... platform-browser-dynamic,
  router
- @angular/cli: 1.5.4
- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33
- @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.21
- @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.37
- @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
- @ngtools/webpack: 1.8.4
- @schematics/angular: 0.1.7 typescript: 2.4.2 webpack: 3.8.1

Sorry, I don't know how to get more information. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have your project committed to a source control repository or backed up anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, I have it on github but the last time I uploaded was two days ago and I don't want to do everything again.